# How to remove multiple R.java if it keeps on regenerating?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two `BuildConfig.java` and `R.java` files and everytime I delete either of them it just regenerates. Is there anyway I can delete the duplicate without it regenerating?

I tried renaming the package using `F2` and the old package still stayed there.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: can you post screenshot?

Comment: Which packages are they in?

Comment: How can you have two R files in the same folder? I assume that if they are not in the same folder they are in different project and there is no problem?

Comment: Yes sorry different packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename your src package and you will also need to rename the android package with android tools which refactors your AndroidManifest.xml

It also doesn't hurt to run a project clean after.

Reference:
http://movivations.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/change-package-name-in-android-motodev-eclipse/

Comment: Updated answer with an example walk through. Looks like you also have to refactor through android tools which changes the manifest

Comment: ill give that a try, not sure how to find the IDE? I am using the latest Version of Android SDK Eclipse

Comment: It worked! Changed it through the manifest file `package="yourpackagename"`

Comment: Cool. Eclipse is the IDE just for your reference.

Comment: Oh woops! should have mentioned that in the question!